# Is it possible to explain radiation of an accelerated charged particle via the Unruh effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

From the point view of a noninertial observer, if a charged particle accelerates then it can catch the Unruh particle and excite. After that, the charged particle emits it and falls back to its ground state.

If we accept radiation of an accelerated charged particle like that then we can say the same thing for an accelerated normal particle (without charge) and conclude it radiates too.

How to solve this paradox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, electromagnetic radiation of accelerated charges can be understood in the accelerated reference frame by means of the Unruh effect, as shown by Higuchi, Matsas, and Sudarsky in [*Phys. Rev. D* **45**, R3308(R) (1992)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.45.R3308) and [*Phys. Rev. D* **46**, 3450 (1992)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.46.3450). The emission of a photon in the inertial frame corresponds to either the emission *or* the absorption of a photon in the accelerated frame.

An important remark though is that an accelerated particle will not absorb or emit a photon in either reference frame unless it is charged. This is because this absorption or emission will only happen if there is an interaction between the particle and the photon field, which only happens if the particle is charged. Hence, neutral particles won't radiate.

In other words, neutral particles don't radiate because they can't "catch" (or release) Unruh particles. To do so, they would need to interact with the photon field, but they don't.

**Remark:** I'm considering only quantum electrodynamics in this answer, meaning I'm ignoring more complicated interactions that could happen at higher loop levels in the Standard Model. After all, we are trying to understand a prediction of classical electrodynamics (radiation by accelerated charges).

Comment: Why a normal particle cant absort unruh particle?

Comment: @reza The relevant Unruh particles in here are still photons. Since neutral particles do not interact with photons, there's no way for them to absorb a photon. Absorption is an interaction.